# Why does my router.push() on the same route with different params only display correctly after following it twice?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

So I have a profile page where people can follow links to the profiles of their friends. These lead to the same route, however with a different id. I have links that work, however they only work after clicking on one at least once before. The URL also does not change on the first request. The only thing I could see creating this problem would be because I have to get the Userdata from my server first. Does anyone have an idea what could cause this?
Everything is made with Vue.js and Ionic

Below you can see my mounted.

```
  mounted: function(){

    this.currentuser = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("User"));

    this.getProfileData();
    for(var i = 0 ; i < this.currentuser.friends.length ; i++){
      console.log(this.currentuser.friends[i]);
      this.getUserData(this.currentuser.friends[i], i);
    }


  },
```

Below you can see my methods.

```
methods: {
    getUserData: function(email, key){

      fetch("/getUserEntrybyEmail", {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          "Content-type" : "application/json"
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify( { "email" : email } ),
      }).then(response=>{
        if(response.status==200){
        return response.json();}
        else{
          console.log("Access Denied.")
        }
      }).then((data)=>{

        Vue.set(this.Friendsdata,key,data);
        console.log(this.Friendsdata);
        this.$forceUpdate();


      })



    },
    openUserPage: function(userid){
    console.log(userid)
    this.$router.push({ name: 'profiles', params: { id: userid }});
    this.$router.go();
  },
    getProfileData: function(){


      fetch("/getDBEntrybyId", {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          "Content-type" : "application/json"
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify( { "id" : this.$route.params.id } ),
      }).then(response=>{
        if(response.status==200){
        return response.json();}
        else{
          console.log("Access Denied.")
        }
      }).then((data)=>{

        this.profileData = data;
        this.$forceUpdate();


      })
    }
  }

};
```

This is where I call openUserpage.

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <NavBar/>
    <ion-content padding>
      {{profileData.vorname}} haha
      <br/>
      Friends:
      <ion-list v-if="currentuser.id==profileData.id">
        <ion-item v-for="friend in Friendsdata" :key="friend"> {{friend.vorname}} {{friend.nachname}} <br/> <ion-button @click="openUserPage(friend.id)">Visit Profile</ion-button></ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you show where are you calling openUserPage? Also, would be great if you can reproduce this in a fidlde.

Comment: @Himanshu

I edited my original post. I tried to do a fiddle, but I'm kinda new to all this stuff and didnt manage to really do it...